# vue-cli-service: choose folders to include/exclude when building project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm new in Vue.js, and I really need your help on this.
I have a vue.js project that has a structure like this:

```
src
--App.vue

--modules(folder)

---feature1(folder)
------view11.vue
------view12.vue

---feature2(folder)
------view21.vue
------view22.vue

---feature3(folder)
------view31.vue
------view32.vue
```

I would like for example to build only an app that have feature1 & feature2 (without feature3)

How can I do this?